# jQueryUI Autocomplete results <ul> not positioned properly in IE7

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here is my implementation of my results of my jQueryUI Autocomplete function:

```
appendTo: "#results",
    open: function(){
        var position = $("#results").position(),
        left = position.left, 
        top = position.top;

        $("#results > ul").css({
            left: (left + 15) + "px",
            top: (top + 30) + "px", 
            width: (206) + "px", 
            float: "left"
         });
    },
```

It works on Firefox, Chrome and even on IE8 and IE9 but not on IE7. What did I do wrong? Please help.

Comment: you didn't do any wrong..microsoft did!!

Comment: @RajatSinghal, is there any workaroound for this that might work? I am really desperate.

Comment: @RajatSinghal, on second thought please teach me a hack on css on ie7.

Comment: you need to see errors its throwing in console..open console by pressing f12, in scripts tab, see errors, and google for them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your own positioning, you might try the jquery-ui positioning, for example:

```
appendTo: "#results",
position: {'my': 'left top', 'at': 'left top', 'of': '#results'}
```

You can have it add in padding for you too, something like:

```
position: {'my': 'left top', 'at': 'left+15 top+30', 'of': '#results'}
```

More information on jQuery UI Positioning: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

I actually stumbled across this question when I was having trouble with IE7 positioning. Turns out I was anchoring `'at': 'left bottom'` of my container, which worked fine in the other browsers, but caused IE7 to shift my results below the container. Once I switched everything to left top, it is working great.

Comment: Yep, I used this solution and it quite gave me what I wanted. In fact in positioning the jqueryui autocomplete, this one is most suggested solution. Thank you for the answer though.:)